# Object reference not set to an instance of an object when need to use HttpContext in Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

i write a attribute for accesslevel in asp core .

this is my code :

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class AllowAccessAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly IDomainUnitOfWork unitofwork;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContext;
    private readonly string _name;

    public AllowAccessAttribute(string name)
    {
        _name = name;

    }
    public string Name => _name;

    public AllowAccessAttribute(IDomainUnitOfWork unitofwork, IHttpContextAccessor httpContext)
    {
        this.unitofwork = unitofwork;
        this.httpContext = httpContext;
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {

        var userId = httpContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId<long>();

    }

}
```

and use the typefilter :

```
   public class AutourizeAccessAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public AutourizeAccessAttribute(string permission) : base(typeof(AllowAccessAttribute))
    {
        Arguments = new object[] { permission };
    }
}
```

and use that by this way :

```
[AutourizeAccess("Change Use Active Status")]
```

but when i run the code it show me this error :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

in this line `var userId = httpContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId<long>();`

**whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ????**

Comment: `httpContext.HttpContext.User.Identity` - one of them is null. Try debugging.

Comment: The user object is null before the client is authenticated.